# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter' -_-

Tags: flutter

Hey guys Im currently working on a flutter app, I am using MAC for the development, before it was working fine and suddenly when I ran the code today this is the output of XCode:

```
2019-12-20 09:39:52.584713+0800 Runner[9120:131811] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:51798/Bd8XcvSU0Bw=/
2019-12-20 09:39:52.916290+0800 Runner[9120:131800] flutter: null
2019-12-20 09:39:53.414262+0800 Runner[9120:131639] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000084dde0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2019-12-20 09:39:53.455205+0800 Runner[9120:131639] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e43802e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ddfeb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x000000010d8e53a6 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 575
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010d8e5b64 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 45
    4   Runner                              0x000000010b10492f -[FLTVideoPlayer initWithAsset:frameUpdater:] + 191
    5   Runner                              0x000000010b108b2d -[FLTVideoPlayerPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 1581
    6   Flutter                             0x000000010b6d64fd __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 104
    7   Flutter                             0x000000010b66fec0 _ZNK7flutter21PlatformMessageRouter21HandlePlatformMessageEN3fml6RefPtrINS_15PlatformMessageEEE + 166
    8   Flutter                             0x000000010b673780 _ZN7flutter15PlatformViewIOS21HandlePlatformMessageEN3fml6RefPtrINS_15PlatformMessageEEE + 38
    9   Flutter                             0x000000010b6d0db3 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7flutter5Shell29OnEngineHandlePlatformMessageEN3fml6RefPtrINS2_15PlatformMessageEEEE4$_31NS_9allocatorIS8_EEFvvEEclEv + 57
    10  Flutter                             0x000000010b6823f1 _ZN3fml15MessageLoopImpl10FlushTasksENS_9FlushTypeE + 123
    11  Flutter                             0x000000010b687742 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin11OnTimerFireEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPS0_ + 26
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e39b944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e39b632 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e39ac8a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e3959fe __CFRunLoopRun + 2238
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e394e16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114578bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001179c3b48 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    19  Runner                              0x000000010b0d4580 main + 112
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001107d4c25 start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am really looking forward for your help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Icloud deleted my "background.mp4" file and it's caused the crashing.